# Problem importing dropdown dependencies: ^ 1.0.2 in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm having trouble using link dropdown import:

https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown

As the image below I did the import correctly, but an error is occurring. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Dropdown Usage Process:

`pubspec.yaml` dependencies added `dropdown 1.0.2` as shown in the image -

[image]

I performed the import correctly but gave the error as the first image -

[image]

Comment: What IDE do you use? Maybe close the IDE

Comment: Visual Studio Code https://code.visualstudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

did you run this command
flutter get

Once you run this command, please hot reload your app. If that doesn't work, try to re-run app from start.

This should fix your problem, if problem still persist please contact package developer or leave issue on package github repo.